# Run nano server container on a Raspberry PI 3

Tags: windows, docker, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I have a PI3 and I wan't to run nano server docker containers on it. Is this possible?

Can i install docker on IoT core? Or are there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can run docker on pi3. i confirmed this using offical debian as operation system, i'm not sure IoT core.

attentions: images must support arm can run on pi3 docker

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/

here is some pi3 supported images
https://hub.docker.com/u/hypriot/?page=2

Comment: The OP is referring to Windows Nano Server, not Linux images as you link to here.

Answer (score 0):

for Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 can install official release of Windows 10 IoT Core and Windows 10 IoT Core Insider Preview.

Nano Sever installation, is from virtualization environment from Hyper V .

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft (back in May, 2018), you can or will be able to run Nano Server containers on IoT Core:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/nano-in-semi-annual-channel

also see this question:
[Can Docker containers run in Windows IoT Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370938/can-docker-containers-run-in-windows-iot-core)