# Can Docker run on Windows 10 IoT Enterprise?

Tags: windows, docker, windowsiot

A similar question was asked for Windows 10 IoT Core: [Can Docker containers run in Windows IoT Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370938/can-docker-containers-run-in-windows-iot-core)

However, can Docker run on Windows 10 IoT **Enterprise**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker can run on **Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 64bit Build 16299 or later**, with Hyper-V and Components enabled. See [requirements](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#system-requirements).

Note: "Windows 10 IoT Enterprise" is identical to "Windows 10 Enterprise", [it only differs in license type, not core system](https://www.high-rely.com/2018/06/14/windows-10-iot-enterprise/#:%7E:text=WIndows%2010%20IoT%20Enterprise%20is,OEMs%20in%20an%20embedded%20market.&text=The%20difference%20is%20simply%20the,the%20OS%20is%20loaded%20on.).